# Transition matrix and change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I would like to explain the concepts I just learnt as best as I can, I know it's not a question but if there is any slight inconsistency please correct me. Thank you for your time!
$$$$
**Bases**
I am using the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, and say there is another basis my friend Jennifer uses (Paying my respects to 3Blue1Brown)$$C=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2\\
    1 & 3\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
This is Jennifers basis in terms of MY basis, otherwise her's would look exactly like the one for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and hence mine.

This converts HER coordinates into MY coordinates. And can be considered to be a change of basis matrix $P_{BC}$.
$$$$
**Transformation matrix**
A transformation matrix $[T]_{BB}$ where B is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ can convert a vector $v$ in $V$ into another vector $u$ in $U$ with respect to the same basis B. And U, V are in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Lets say $[T]_{CB}$ is the same transformation matrix BUT it converts a vector $v_{B}$ to a vector $u_{C}$ where $u_{C}$ is with respect to a basis $C$ instead of $u_{B}$ which is with respect to basis B

If the transformation $[T]_{CB}$ doesn't do anything hence
$$T(v) = v$$

It is simply a change of basis matric $P_{CB}$ that puts a vector $v_{B}$ in terms of basis $C$